# Why should I repay a loan?

Tags: crusader-kings-3

While in CKII there was a opinion penalty towards the clergy, in CK3 I cannot find any downsides on having a loan.

The Wiki says that it *"Removes all negative effects associated with holy order loans"*, but I couldn't find any such effect.

Is there some hidden effect I didn't notice nor encounter yet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the loan is not repaid then the Holy Order will start making demands.

Usually they want one of your holdings, which will then no longer give you taxes nor levies.

Comment: And… do they allow me to chose which one? And they consider the debt settled when they do? Because in that case this could be **much** cheaper than paying back the loan :D

Comment: @o0'. no, they choose. I don't think it settles the loan either.

Comment: Ok thanks, will wait for a few days just in case more answers come, and will accept later :)